# Como habilitar a opção "Android" na aba de criação de projetos do Eclipse?

Tags: android-eclipse

Como habilitar a opção "Android" na aba de criação de projetos do Eclipse?

[image: Eclipse]

Quando clico em File > New > Other, não aparece a opção Android para começar um projeto de aplicativo. O que eu faço?

Comment: Tens de instalar os plugins para Android.

Comment: Eu tenho, mano. Não sei oq ainda falta. Me faz um passo-a-passo, pra eu ver se esqueci de algum.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html